# Playing a video with JMF

Tags: java, oop, media-player, jmf

Is there a simple way to play a video. The application I am building gives information about movies to the user. There are next/previous buttons that flip through each movie. For each movie I want to have a play trailer button, which when clicked will pop up a new frame/panel and will play that movies trailer. The path name for the video will be passed into a movie object when read in from a .CSV file.

All examples I have looked at so far I find complex and don't work. Ideally i'm looking for a few lines of code that will open the player, and play the video.